# Form M groups having buildings of equal height from N buildings

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, recursion

I have been given N buildings with their height.

I have to form groups of size M having equal height buildings. Given, I can destroy buildings of greater height to make their height equal to the smaller buildings.

I have to find the minimum number of buildings to be destroyed so as to form exactly N/M groups.Given,N is always divisible by M.

for eg:

N=8,M=4

Height of buildings: 6 4 5 1 5 2 3 2

Answer:5

We can destroy two building of height 5's to two 2's to form the first group and then destroy building of height 3,4,6 to height 1 to form second group having buildings of equal height 1.

So, we form 2(N/M) groups of size 4(M).Minimum number of buildings to be destroyed are 5.

N=8,M=4

Height Of Buildings: 1 1 1 2 4 4 4 4

Answer:1

Can anyone Please give me some hint on this.

Comment: I dont understand why the answer is 5. we can change building 6 into height 1, and  change building 4 to height 3. Then we have 4(M) groups, each group has two(N/M) buildings, The height of each groups are: `1,2,3,5`. thus, we have just changed 2 buildings, building 6 and building 4.

Comment: We have to make groups of size 4(M) and the count of the groups should be (N/M) here which is 2.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm

1. Put all the height (increasing order) in a hash (say ordered map on STL) - key as height, data as frequency of that height.
2. For N/M times, get freq (say sum) and keep adding.
3. Result = N - sum.

Pseudo Code

```
arr[] = {6 4 5 1 5 2 3 2}
map<int, int, greater<int>> mp;
for(auto elem : arr)
{
    if(data exist)
        increase freq
    else
        insert key with freq as 1.
}
sum = 0
for(i=0 to N/M)
    sum += freq of mp[i]

Result = N - sum
```

Comment: I don't think this is right answer.I have many counterexamples.                         
for eg:n=8,m=4 Height: 2 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 Here answer should be 1.But by your approach it comes out to be 4.